# Merging two vectors with an 'or'

Tags: r

I have 2 vectors, each of which has some NA values.

```
a <- c(1, 2, NA, 3, 4, NA)
b <- c(NA, 6, 7, 8, 9, NA)
```

I'd like to combine these two with `a` result that uses the value from a if it is non-NA, otherwise the value from `b`.

So the result would look like:

```
c <- c(1, 2, 7, 3, 4, NA)
```

How can I do this efficiently in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
a[is.na(a)] <- b[is.na(a)]
a
## [1]  1  2  7  3  4 NA
```

Or, if you don't want to overwrite `a`, just do

```
c <- a
c[is.na(c)] <- b[is.na(c)]
c
## [1]  1  2  7  3  4 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
> c <- ifelse(is.na(a), b, a)
> c
[1]  1  2  7  3  4 NA
```